# How do you increase the distance between staves in Lilypond?

Tags: spacing, lilypond

I would like there to be more vertical space between the staves.

I am totally lost on this so I didn't know what to try. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/fitting-music-onto-fewer-pages) for documentation on this. The property your are interested in is `system-system-spacing`.  My `\paper` block looks like this (adjust to taste):

```
\paper {
  system-system-spacing =
    #'((basic-distance . 8) 
       (minimum-distance . 4)
       (padding . 2)
       (stretchability . 60)) % defaults: 12, 8, 1, 60
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a code snippet so that we can better help you. It's difficult to answer a question when little details about desired outcome nor any code is provided.

In Lilypond, the distance between staves can be adjusted by setting the `between-system-space` property. This property determines the amount of space between staves within a system, as well as the amount of space between systems.

Comment: Will do in future. Sorry. How do you set the between-system-space property?

Comment: It used to be a paper block variable, like `system-system-spacing` but I don't think it's used anymore.